# Creating Div using Zend_Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to hidden/store dynamically generated div inside parent div.I have taken the following piece of code from my form page.

```
     ....
    $existing_billing_address = array();
    if (count($all_addr) > 0) {
        $hidden_existing_addr_div = '';
        foreach ($all_addr as $addrvalue) {
            $existing_billing_address[$addrvalue['address_id']] = $addrvalue['address1'];
            $exname = $addrvalue['address_name'];
            $exaddress1 = $addrvalue['address1'];
            $exaddress2 = $addrvalue['address2'];
            $excountry = $addrvalue['country'];
            $exstate = $addrvalue['state'];
            $excity = $addrvalue['city'];
            $exzipcode = $addrvalue['zipcode'];
            $exphone = $addrvalue['phone'];
            $exaddress_id = $addrvalue['address_id'];
            $hidden_existing_addr_div .= "<div id='selectBilling_" . $exaddress_id . "' style='display:none'>";
            $hidden_existing_addr_div .= $exname . "||" . $exaddress1 . "||" . $exaddress2 . "||" . $excountry . "||" . $exstate . "||" . $excity . "||" . $exzipcode . "||" . $exphone . "||" . $exaddress_id;
            $hidden_existing_addr_div .= "</div>";
        }
    }
....
```

This will generate some thing like below,

```
> <div style="display: none;" id="selectBilling_40">Dinesh 
> billing||billing add1||Billing
> add2||IN||TA||Chennai||625001||1234567891||40</div><div
> style="display: none;" id="selectBilling_41">kumar shipping||shipping
> add1||shipping add2||US||CA||chennai||72944||1234567891||41</div>
```

I want to store the above hidden div using zend_form.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Well, in this case you can use a zend_form, hidden it and then store its values.

Comment: using this "Zend_Form_Element_Hidden" will generate hidden text box not div...is it posssible to create div using zend_form.

Comment: First use a Zend Form (not element), than change how it looks using setDecorators. Anyway, you don't need to hide every element, you can just hide the whole form.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case you can use a `Zend_Form`, hidden it and then store its values so you can make validation too.
If you want to display it as a div, you can change how it looks using `Zend_Decorator`. Anyway, you don't need to hide every element, you can just hide the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

I have used hidden text box, Using jquery i ve taken the hidden text box value and create DIV with that content and clear the input box value.

```
$(function(){
    var val = $('#edit_existing_billingaddr').val();
    $('#edit_existing_billingaddr').after('<div>'+val+'</div>');
    $('#edit_existing_billingaddr').val('');
});
```

But i am not use zend completely here.

Comment: This is not a good solution because in this way, you're not using zend framework as it should and you're not using the power of zend form, validators and filters.

Comment: yes,can you tell me how do we change input to div using decorator